# advice on modeling schema to have better access to foreign entity

Tags: mongodb

I am fairly new to modeling on MongoDB--please consider this simple example schema

```
const userSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String
});

const addressSchema = Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    street: Schema.Types.String,
    city: Schema.Types.String,
    state: Schema.Types.String,
    zip: Schema.Types.String,
});
```

Since querying addresses by user will be a constant job, what is the right choice to make?

a) place an "addresses" field in User schema as

```
addresses: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
```

b) having a virtual property on User

```
userSchema.virtual('addresses', {
  ref: 'Address',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'user'
});
```

Is this a good use of virtual type, according to mongoose docs?

> are document properties that you can get and set but that do not get
>   persisted to MongoDB. The getters are useful for formatting or
>   combining fields, while setters are useful for de-composing a single
>   value into multiple values for storage

It doesn't quite fall in the situation they describe, so I'm not sure if it applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following schema may be better to match your requirement.

```
{
    name: String,
    username: String,
    address: {
        street: String,
        city: String,
        state: String,
        zip: String,
    }
}
```

Try to avoid having multiple collections like a relational database. Joining is a costly operation in NoSQL databases.

References:

[6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

[6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2)

[6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 3](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)

Comment: Interesting. in case the user had more than one address, that field would need to be an array, right ?


More, if i wanted to save ex, books the user rented, by the same logic, books would be defined in the user schema too ?

That would solve the question of getting all address for a specific user, but what i wanted to search all addresses for a city, this design would not be very suitable.

Comment: Yes, the address field should be an array in that case. You can a new book field to the schema to store the books as well. You can search the address for a city using MongoDB aggregation pipeline framework. Its a very powerful tool to query against mongo documents. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/